# Of 6 seniors and 7 juniors, 5 will be selected for a scholarship. What is the probability that exactly 3 of 5 students selected will be seniors?

Tags: probability

I know that the formula for finding exact probability is:

$$\binom{n}{r}p^rq^{n-r}$$

but i can't quite figure out how to find my values for $n$ and $r$. Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: I wouldn't use this 'formula' here. Think about the general event of picking 5 students out of 6 seniors and 7 juniors, and about the specific event you are describing: 3 of these 5 are seniors, and thus obviously two are juniors.

Comment: @Studentmath can I start off this problem by setting up 13C5 and then multiplying that by 3/5?

Comment: The denominator will indeed be $\binom{13}{5}$. The numerator will be the number of ways to choose $3$ seniors **and** $2$ juniors. We are of course assuming that all choices are equally likely, a in-real-world very dubious assumption.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider I am choosing the students one by one. Also consider a selection step. What is the Prob. that a senior will be selected? It's $\frac{6}{6+7}=\frac{6}{13}$. So, prob. that a junior will be selected is $\frac{7}{13}$.

Now, I need to choose 3 seniors out of 6. This can be done in $6 \choose 3$ ways. Now, each student is chosen independently of each other. Thus, the probability that 3 seniors will be chosen is, $6 \choose 3$*Pr(3 seniors chosen)*Pr(2 juniors chosen)=${6 \choose 3} {\frac{6}{13}}^3{\frac{7}{13}}^2$

**I have found (and am notified as well) that this solution is not correct. @Studentmath gave the correct solution. I would request the questioner to accept his solution instead of mine. Sorry for all the confusions.**

Comment: But nothing states that you are choosing them one by one.

Comment: This answer is correct only if we assume that a scholarship winner is chosen, then a scholarship winner is chosen (perhaps the same person), then a scholarship winner is chosen (perhaps the same person as the winner of the first scholarship, and even of the second, and so on (sampling with replacement). That is I think not the natural interpretation of the problem.

Comment: Plus, correct me if I am wrong, but in that case it would be $5 \choose 3$ ways, not $6 \choose 3$, as you need to choose 3 seniors out of 5 scholarships.

Comment: @Studentmath: Yes, I assumed the $6$ was a typo.

Answer (score 2):

The sample space in this case is the random choice of 5 for scholarship, out of 6 seniors + 7 juniors. That means, $13 \choose 5$. The event you are looking for is the event that 3 are chosen from the seniors, and thus 2 are chosen from the juniors. By multipication law that leads us to: ${6} \choose {3}$ * ${7} \choose {2}$. So we get that the probability is:

$P(E)=\frac{\binom{6}{3} * \binom {7}{2}}{\binom {13}{5}}$

Comment: I do not understand why the denominator is ${15} \choose {3}$. I would think that it would be ${13} \choose {3}$ since $6 + 7 = 13$.I have a feeling you have an editing error.

Comment: Actually should be 13 choose 5, but yes it's an editing error. Cheers!